# Detecting a cycle in a linked list using Java

Tags: java, beginner, programming-challenge, linked-list

I'm solving [HackerRank "Linked Lists: Detect a Cycle"](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-linked-list-cycle/problem) challenge.

> A linked list is said to contain a cycle if any node is visited more
>   than once while traversing the list.
>
> Complete the function provided in the editor below. It has one
>   parameter: a pointer to a `Node` object named `head` that points to the head
>   of a linked list. Your function must return a boolean denoting whether
>   or not there is a cycle in the list. If there is a cycle, return true;
>   otherwise, return false.
>
> **Note:** If the list is empty, `head` will be null.

```
/*
Detect a cycle in a linked list. Note that the head pointer may be 'null' if the list is empty.

A Node is defined as: 
    class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
    }
*/

boolean hasCycle(Node head) {
    HashSet<Node> seen = new HashSet<Node>();

    Node current = head;
    while (current != null && current.next != null) {
        if (seen.contains(current)) {
            return true;
        }

        seen.add(current);
        current = current.next;
    }

    return false;
}
```

As a beginner Java developer, what can be improved here?

Comment: `200_success` already suggested nice improvements, and this solution is perfectly fine, but you might want to be aware that there is another algorithm that doesn't use additional memory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663147/1550964

Comment: I am not sure if you want spoilers, but I think you can get a better complexity than using this algorithm when you know the maximum number of elements in the list (which is given in the hackerrank task). This information can help a lot. If you do not know the (max) number of elements your algorithm is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method should be `public`.

Testing for the `current.next != null` condition is unnecessary. Also, consider writing the loop as a `for` loop for clarity:

```
for (Node current = head; current != null; current = current.next) {
    …
}
```

You don't need to call `seen.contains()`, because `seen.add()` will return `false` if the item you are adding is already in the set.